# can't reference netstandard2.0 library if a reference to CodeAnalysis.CSharp is present

Tags: c#, dll, shared-libraries, .net-standard-2.0

## Background

Originally I wrote multiple code generators (need netstandard2.0), and wanted to extract common functionalities into a library (also netstandard2.0). However, when trying to reference the library I always get an error that the .dll file was not found, even though it is there. I spent 3 hours browsing the web and debugging and below you find a MRE. I'm not yet exactly sure that it is the exact same problem I'm facing, since it's complaining about Microsoft's dll and not my own, but I still hope this fix to this will also be a fix to my problem. I'm aware that a newer version of the package is available, but I couldn't get the code generator to run with a newer version, so I'm sticking to this one.

## Question

How can I get this running?

## Steps to reproduce:

In VS 17.9.3, create a new Console Application, TargetFramework net8.0.

In the same solution, add a new Library project, TargetFramework netstandard2.0.

*MyLib.csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

*Class1.cs*

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace MyLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int GetNumber()
        {
            AttributeSyntax node = null;
            return 1337;
        }
    }
}
```

In the same solution, add a second new library project, TargetFramework netstandard2.0:

*MySecondLib.csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyLib\MyLib.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

*Class2.cs*

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using MyLib;
using System;

namespace MySecondLib
{
    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        public void PrintNumber()
        {
            AttributeSyntax node = null;
            Console.WriteLine(GetNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

For the original console Application, use the following file:
*NetStandardReproduction.csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MySecondLib\MySecondLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

*Program.cs*

```
using MySecondLib;

namespace NetStandardReproduction
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new Class2();
            obj.PrintNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

It will build fine, but when you run it it fails with an unhandle Exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

If you remove the reference from both packages and comment the lines with `AttributeSyntax` it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) (and [Use functionality from NuGet packages](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages) section of the Source Generators Cookbook):

> You might be using a dependency purely as a development harness and might not want to expose that to projects that will consume your package. In this scenario, you can use the `PrivateAssets` metadata to control this behavior.

Basically `PrivateAssets=all` means that the consumers of this library will not reference dependency marked with it, hence the final console app will not have `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` referenced, hence error.

Either remove/modify `PrivateAssets` property in the libraries or add the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` as an explicit dependency to the final app:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MySecondLib\MySecondLib.csproj"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Hm, thanks, that answers my question, but my original problems remains unsolved. I will have to find another way to reproduce that.

Comment: @infinitezero was glad to help and sorry to hear that the actual problem was not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **PrivateAssets="all"** attribute or change with **PrivateAssets="compile"**